# Is there a word for "a drop of water that comes into contact with eyes"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am just looking for one word, when a drop of water come into eyes.
 Is there is any word for this ?

Comment: You mean tears?

Comment: What exactly are you asking for here? The drop itself, or the action when it splashes in your eyes, or the verb? Also, in your native language is there a word for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> John Doe is using an eye dropper. Drops of water [are dripping](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=h9zfuYLkodIC&pg=PA61&lpg=PA61&dq=%22drop+dripped+into+his+eye%22&source=bl&ots=sLcJ4MIFT6&sig=3dEG9Sp3Umop72n32VnPbvC-IHk&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=y2FXU5PeIcakPa3tgPAO&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22drop%20dripped%20into%20his%20eye%22&f=false) (or ***dropping***) into his eye.

Jane Doe was fixing a leak under the kitchen sink as a drop of water **splashed** into her eye.

> While playing in its pen with water balls, Baby Doe accidentally **splashed** a drop of water into its eye.

Comment: It can be dripped or splashed or drizzled or dropped, that's what drops do (there is nothing special here about eyes).

Comment: @Mitch Saying "a droplet splashed (or drizzled) into my eye" sounds to me like it happened by accident. http://www.facetimewithsharon.com/2011/02/face-126-adventures-in-short-ribs.html

Comment: NG: "I splashed a drop of water into my eye". That doesn't sound by accident.

Comment: @Mitch Sure. Still and all, it sounds weird to my ear, especially if the drop comes out of a dropper.

Comment: NG that's the difference between semantics and pragmatics. The 'accident' is all about the context of an eye-dropper, not the given sentence in isolation.

Answer (score 0):

Lacrimation: [the secretion of tears, especially in abnormal abundance.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lacrimation)

Or, did you mean to ask the term for water splashed/introduced externally?

Comment: lacrimation seem good word but what is word for splashed/introduced externally ?

Comment: Don't know -yet ;-)

Comment: I think *epiphoric* is a more commonly used word than lacrimation, but this isn't the word you're looking for...

Comment: yes your right ! I want something emotionally and generally we can use it !

Comment: @Tucker epiphoric is the technical term for an excess of lacrimation.